# android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-4/tools/dx: line 77: exec: java: not found

Tags: android

android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-4/tools/dx: line 77: exec: java: not found

I configured Android  plateform on netbeans6.8 and created an android project, getting compile time error: android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-4/tools/dx: line 77: exec: java: not found

Please any solution?.

Answer (score 5):

If you are getting that error it means that Java is either not installed or not in your PATH. If you are using Ubuntu, you can install Java using the command `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit the dx** file in your android/tools directory to add the following just before the last line like below:

```
if ! 'exec java -version'; then
    export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/jre/bin
fi 2>/dev/null
exec java $javaOpts -jar "$jarpath" "$@"
```

with this addition it's worked for me.. I hope this can help.. ;-)

Comment: ...what dx file? Can you be more specific?

Comment: what is dx file?